# UK visa at the border

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, family

Our kids have German passports but my husband and I have a permanent residence card. We want to travel to the UK by road. Can we get a visa at the border by providing the necessary documents, as our kids are travelling with us?

Comment: They have a nice website for finding out if you need a visa: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa - If you need one, you will need to apply in advance.

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: @Nazia The UK does not issue visas ‘on the spot’. Depending on your nationality/personal circumstances you may qualify for visa-free entry; if not, you need to apply for a visa in advance.

Answer (score 4):

No, the UK doesn't issues visas on arrival.

Thus, if you normally need a visa for the UK, well, you will need it.